# Protect range to allow editing of **values only** (ie. protect all formatting)

Tags: google-sheets

I'm thinking this is not possible with the current version of Google Sheets, but thought I'd ask anyhow:

I want users to be able to enter values in a specific range within a spreadsheet, but I want to prevent them from altering the formatting (in particular the data validation and conditional formatting).  I'd also like to prevent them from adding new rows/columns or from deleting rows/columns.

Is this possible?

Comment: not with the out-of-the box tools, but i imagine that you could develop a simple onEdit trigger with GAS that immediately re-applies all the "correct" formatting to the active range when a change is made, like a stylesheet that repaints the worksheet whenever there is change.

Comment: This question isn't about programming related to Google Sheets, so it is off-topic for Stack Overflow. It belongs on [WebApps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: There does appear to be a programming-related workaround for this issue, in an answer to a similar question, at https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/105031/49181

Answer (score 1):

To protect the conditional formatting, I make the range one row or one column bigger than what it needs to be and protect this extra row or column. Then, the conditional formatting including protected cells in their range cannot be modified anymore.

Comment: This does not prevent an editor from changing the data validation and formatting of other cells in the row/column.

Answer (score 0):

The protect sheet options can limit another users ability to add/remove rows however I spent a great deal of time trying to resolve the conditional formatting issue as well. In the end I ended up using a couple of workarounds;

- I used appscript for conditional formatting. it was the most effective solution however as I'm not well versed on writing code I found it quite cumbersome. Partial example below.
- The quicker work around I also used was to conditional format the cells next to the user edited cells which I would then protect.

```
if (values[i] == 'SUB') {
      sheet
      .setRowHeight(i+1, 19)
      .getRange('A'+n+':CB'+n)
      .setBackgroundColor('#b7b7b7')
      .setFontFamily("Abel").setFontSize(6).setFontColor('white').setFontWeight("bold")
      .setVerticalAlignment(DocumentApp.VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE).setHorizontalAlignment("center")
      .setBorder(null, null, true, null, null, null,'white',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK)   /////// top,left,bottom,right,vertical,horizontal,color,style;

      sheet.getRange('O'+n+':O'+n).setBackgroundColor('white')
      sheet.getRange('AF'+n+':AF'+n).setBackgroundColor('white')

      sheet.getRange('AJ'+n+':AJ'+n).setBorder(null, null, null, true, null, null,'white',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK)
      sheet.getRange('AN'+n+':AN'+n).setBorder(null, null, null, true, null, null,'white',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK)
      sheet.getRange('AR'+n+':AR'+n).setBorder(null, null, null, true, null, null,'white',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK)
      sheet.getRange('AV'+n+':AV'+n).setBorder(null, null, null, true, null, null,'white',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this on a fresh sheet. Right click the sheet name, choose protect sheet, choose "except certain cells" and you probably have it fine from there...

You may have an old sheet as it doesn't work on some existing sheets. If you click "data" and only see "named and protected ranges" as a single entry instead of 2 separate menu items, you are on an older sheet that won't allow the protection.

Comment: This does not answer the question.  I want to protect the **formatting**, but still allow users to change **data** in the cells.

Answer (score -2):

The best solution and easiest is to Ctrl+Shift+V to paste data as value only. I've been trying to do this as well because we work with sheets that involves copy/pasting from different sources. It's annoying and a waste of time to go and format paint on top of the new data. Practice Ctrl+Shift+V to paste to avoid having to do that. The protected ranges only prevents other users from inputting data. It does not help with keeping format.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not address the question asked. I'm not worried about accidentally altering formatting myself, but rather want to prevent other users from doing so. Trying to educate all of them is a lot of work and is not reliable. I'm hoping to disallow formatting changes completely to avoid the problem.